# drawer to pull next view

Tags: ios, swift, navigation-drawer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am working on a project in which i need to implement the swipe drawer functionality so that user can draw next view by swiping from right to left.
I need to implement the same functionality like in the below examples 
[example 1](https://github.com/yichizhang/YZSwipeBetweenViewController)
[example 2](https://github.com/cwRichardKim/RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers)

above example functionality exectly serves my purpose. But problem is when i pass my view controllers then only white screens appear. 
As in the demo examples of the above projects using the custom viewControllers to draw. But in my case view controllers are already  created and i need to use them.

```
 let pageController: UIPageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .Scroll, navigationOrientation: .Horizontal, options: nil)
    let navigationController: RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers = RKSwipeBetweenViewControllers(rootViewController: pageController)
    navigationController.viewControllerArray.addObjectsFromArray([MyTimelinesTableViewController (), CaptureMomentViewController(), CaptureMomentViewController()])
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem and how the code snippet is related to it.

Comment: I have a project where I have to implement the drawer functionality (same as the examples link) have to implement. as the app is already 70% finish and all the views are created....but the problem is that in every drawer view example they are creating custom views ..but my problem is I already created the views and want to use them instead of creating new one.........examples working fine with custom new views but not with my already created views

Comment: I still don't have a slightest idea of why exactly your views would not work with the libraries you want to use. Please try to explain it better, it is hard to help to fix the problem when the problem itself is not clearly presented. Do you want to get rid of the pageviewcontroller and have it replaced completely with sliding views ? What is the problem at doing that ?

Comment: thanks for your resonse, while reading your message , i strike with solution , i was using xib code insted of storyboard to call view...the code that worked is ""let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
        let redVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Trending")
""